# Min and Max level for Serilog logger sinks

Tags: c#, serilog

We have found `restrictedToMinimumLevel` property exists in serilog but does it also support max level property?

Earlier we have used `NLog` which has min and max levels of logging (https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules).
 We would like to log from `debug to information` in console and `information to warning` in files and `errors` to database. 
 Can we do that using appsettings.json?
 we are using dotnet core 2.2.
 Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is a `.Filter.ByIncluding` and `ByExcluding`, which has access to the level. Have not used it via appsettings.json but in general, the config DSL has equivalents in the json

Answer (score 6):

A little bit late for the answer, but I just had the same question and found a solution. Maybe it will be helpful to somebody like me.

In this case subloggers combined with `Serilog.Expressions` package can be used. Sublogger is a new logger inside your main logger, for which you can set filtering rules. For example, this config says, that `Debug` and `Information` logs will be written to Console sink, and logs with `Information` and `Warning` level will be written to SqlServer sink.

Here is a reference for expression language: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions#language-reference.

JSON config will look like this:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    //... serilog config
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l in ['Debug', 'Information']"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args": {
                  //Console sink config
                }
              }
            ],
           }
         }
      },
      {
        "Name": "Logger",
        "Args": {
          "configureLogger": {
            "Filter": [
              {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                  "expression": "@l in ['Information', 'Warning']"
                }
              }
            ],
            "WriteTo": [
              {
                "Name": "MSSqlServer",
                "Args": {
                  //MSSqlServer sink config
                }
              }
            ]
```