# Show only debug level logs in Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I want to show only debug level of logs, but none of the other levels, below or above the debug level.
Also I want to do that in the configuration in appsettings.json, not in the startup class.
Here is my appsettings.json file

```
 "Serilog": {
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Debug",
  "Override": {
    "System": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Debug"
  }
},
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "http://localhost:5341/",
      "compact": true
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Console"
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "D:\\dev.SmartCity.Peafowls.Logs\\PeafowlsLog_.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] [{EventId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
      "rollingInterval": "Day",
      "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
      "fileSizeLimitBytes": 4194304
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69390898/1543596) answer.
You can filter messages by level.

Like this example:

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Settings.Configuration"],
    "Filter": [
      {
        "Name": "ByExcluding",
        "Args": {
          "expression": "EndsWith(RequestPath, '/SomeEndpoint')"
        }
      }
    ]
```

from [Github](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions) source code.

Comment: Just a note, this requires the `Serilog.Settings.Configuration` nuget package be installed.  If @OP runs into issues, they should be sure to add this package